# Quickest way to change a pair of parenthesis to brackets in vim

Tags: vim, matching, parentheses

I am new to vim and in the process of discovering tons of interesting things that one can using this powerful editor.

One particular thing that I need to do very frequently is to change a pair of parenthesis in the text to square-brackets  (for example to change `( (a+b+c) )` to `[ (a+b+c) ]`) or vice-verso. I now do this by manually changing the two characters `(` and `)` to `[` and `]`.

However, when there is a lot of text in between the parenthesis, it could be difficult to locate the pair of opening and closing parenthesis especially because after changing the first `(` to `[` then the `%` command will no longer be able to find the corresponding `)`.

I was wondering if there is a better and quicker way to make such changes?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would simply do it like this: `%r]^or[`.

Here's an explanation:

- `f(` -- put cursor on first parenthesis you want to change (if it's not already there).
- `%` -- jump to the matching parenthesis.
- `r]` -- replace the parenthesis with a bracket.
- `CTRL-O` -- jump back to to first parenthesis.
- `r[` -- replace the parenthesis with a bracket.

Comment: As LucHermitte mentioned you can also use ```%r]``r[```

Comment: quick note, edit the trailing paren before the leading or else vim won't find the trailing paren using `%`

Answer (score 49):

I personally use https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround as it provides everything I could ever need, reading through the source you can see the solution is non-trivial.

A typical example:

```
Hello("World")
```

with the cursor somewhere between the `()`, you can type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> in normal mode to get:

```
Hello["World"]
```

`surround.vim` is easily installed with either Pathogen or Vundle, personally I prefer vundle. https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim

adding the important commented point:

```
cs([ adds spaces in the block, this should be cs)]
```

Comment: That vundle link is very out of date.

Comment: `cs([` adds spaces in the block, this should be `cs)]`.

Comment: To anyone that uses IdeaVim (with IntelliJ IDEs), vim-surround is already included. You can enable this using `:set surround`.

Answer (score 6):

surround.vim https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

with this plugin, you can (cursor on or in `(`),  `cs([` to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 6):

With [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/#brackets-replacement), I would use `<m-b>(` to change any pair of bracket-like characters (cursor on the first/last character of the pair) to a pair of parenthesis. `<m-b>{` -> curly-brackets, and so on.

For the curious ones, this is [how](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/plugin/common_brackets.vim#L311) it works -- see `s:ChangeTo()`. Internally, I do a ``` %r]``r[ ```, and I have a dedicated treatment for quote characters.

Comment: Upvoting this because I really like the ```%r]``r[``` you mention in a comment to another answer on this page that you're using it deep inside your mappings.  It's using only built-in vim features, and has stuck with me.

Comment: Thanks @Randall. Actually, I've rewritten it lately to support quote characters as well. The function is a little bit more complex now. BTW I've updated to link to the "new" github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Without any plugin it can be done by deleting the content inside the parenthesis and yanking in the new bracket (from anywhere within the bracket):

```
di(a[]<esc>P%2X
```

Obviously more key that using `surround` but but not that many ;-)

## Note

There is no need to remember the sequence of key but only to start by deleting the inside of the brackets. Then it's just normal vim fu.

Comment: That does not look right. It seems to not delete the initial surrounding parens correctly. This is what I came up with: `yi)ca)[<c-r>0]<esc>`

Comment: @Peter, you can change `ca)` to `c%`.

Comment: @peter: I delete the inside of the parentheses, insert some new brackets, insert the deleted content between them, THEN delete the initial surrounding parentheses `2x`

Comment: @mb14 I understand what you are going for. The `2x` to delete the parens will not work where your cursor is after the `%` motion, on the `[`. Instead it will delete a `[` and one more character to the the left. To see this setup the test case, `( (a+b+c) )`. Put your cursor on one of the outer parens and run `:exe "norm! di(a[]\<esc>P%2x"`. This will execute your vim snippet without any mappings you can see what I see.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `2X` not `2x'. Also, it's not really a snippet but something you can do on the fly.

Comment: One character to the right not left. Silly me getting mixed up this morning. @LucHermitte you are correct. Nice vim golf

Comment: I'm actually doing `%r]``r[` deep inside my mappings which is even shorter, and which works only when the cursor is on the first character.

Comment: @mb14 Absolutely! Do not memorize it. It should be noted that breaking this up into multiple steps and not using something like surround will mean the following: 1) More undo history 2) Cannot repeat with `.` (Assuming repeat.vim) 3) Will not properly set `[` and `]` marks. That isn't even mentioning the fact that surround.vim does tags! But it is nice to know that even on a remote system you can handle this scenario without too much trouble.

Comment: How about this variation on @mb14: `di(a<bkspace><bkspace>[]<Esc>P`? Yes, the @mb14 usage of capital `X` to delete is more cool (and is now another tool in my bag), and yes it somehow feels *dirty* to be using a `<bkspace>` in Vim, but I thought I would put it out there and leave others to make up their own mind.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a few of the SO's around this matter (see my comment in the @mb14 answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25405416/1243435)), I was thinking of muscle-memorizing something like this:

```
di(a<bkspace><bkspace>[]<Esc>P
```

but what I really *wanted* to do was this:

```
di(c%[]<Esc>P
```

You will see that you cannot do that because the `c` puts the `()` brackets into your `0` register and therefore you actually need to do this:

```
di("_c%[]<Esc>P
```

or (I was also trying out a 'yank' approach and came up with) this:

```
yi(ca([]<Esc>"0P
```

Okay, neither is too bad, but it occurred to me that this is going to all go much better if I map `<leader>c` to `"_c` so that I have a *real delete* and can do this:

```
di(\c%[]<Esc>P
```

or this:

```
yi(\ca([]<Esc>P
```

Both are pretty close to what I wanted to do, and the thought process has given me one of the most valuable lines in my `$MYVIMRC`:

```
noremap <leader>c "_c
```